# scalastyle is complaining about akka send of boolean

Tags: scala, akka, scalastyle

`sender ! true`

and

`sender ! false`

are generating "Boolean expression can be simplified" warnings by scalastyle.

How can I make these warnings go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the [SimplifyBooleanExpression checker](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-0.8.0.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_SimplifyBooleanExpressionChecker) on the lines where you use `! true` or `! false`.

```
sender ! true // scalastyle:ignore simplify.boolean.expression
```

Or on multiple lines :

```
// scalastyle:off simplify.boolean.expression
sender ! false
// scalastyle:on simplify.boolean.expression
```

Comment: What do you mean ? The `SimplifyBooleanExpressionChecker` will be in your *scalastyle-config.xml* file. Scalastyle sees `! true` and thinks it can be replaced by `false`, it's not smart enough to see that in this case it's the akka `!` operator.